# Output of "Assisted" factory should be @Singleton

Tags: java, guice, inject

I'm currently trying to use Google Guice-3.0 in a small application.

When running this app, the user is prompted to input his name and his password. Since this information is not known until runtime, I use `AssistedInject` to implement my `User` instantiation.

This is where my `UserFactory` comes in. It provides a `User` with the method

```
public User create(@Assisted("Username") String username, 
                   @Assisted("Password") String password);
```

The `User` class is initiated once at the start of the program (after the user input) via

```
User user = getInjector().getInstance(UserFactory.class).create(username, password);
```

and I want to use this instance over the lifetime of the application. I have already set the scope to `@Singleton`.

The problem is, however, I only get errors. Guice is complaining that I haven't passed any variables when calling

```
User user = getInjector().getInstance( User.class );
```

and if I add a `bind( User.class );` into the `configure` method, an error occurs that there was no declaration to the annotation `@Assisted` (since you can put annotations in front of parameters to uniquely identify them - Guice probably thinks it's one of them and demands a dependency to be set (like

```
bind( String.class ).annotatedWith( Assisted.class ).toInstance( username );
```

but this is not a thing that would work (maybe it would via static references but then why use Guice?

Here is an example that you can compile. The commented code causes the error. Especially the last 2 lines are pretty irritating to me.

```
public class KSKB {

    @Singleton
    public static class User {

        public final String name;

        @Inject
        public User(@Assisted("Username") String username) {
            this.name = username;
        }

        public static interface Factory {
            public User create(@Assisted("Username") String username);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {

            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(User.Factory.class));
                // bind( User.class );
            }

        });
        User user = injector.getInstance(User.Factory.class).create("Guice");
        System.out.println(user.name);

        // user = injector.getInstance( User.class ); // doesn't work - throws Exception!!
        // System.out.println( user.name );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think can get what you want because you want to spoil Guice.

Guice wants to manages instances and their creation by itself. You *can* use `Provider` and custom factories like the `Assisted` stuff to create object on your own - even with support from Guice. But you *cannot* feed these instances back into Guice. This means, you cannot tell Guice to use a specific object as the singleton instance.<sup>1</sup>

Possible and easy solutions:

- Determine the user name before creating the injector and use `bindConstant()` in the module to bind the user name. Use the appropriate counterpart in `User`. Then you can mark `User` with `@Singleton` and Guice will honour it.
- User `bind(User.class).toInstance(myUser);`. This is similar to the first proposal, because the required username must be fetched before Guice is up and running.
- Do not inject `User` but an intermediate object `UserHolder` (or `UserManager`) which is the singleton. This object has methods to store the actual user and to fetch it. Your initialisation code will fetch that holder (which is empty at that time) and put the created `User` into the holder. Other parts of your application will also inject `UserHolder`.

---

<sup>1</sup> without *dirty* tricks at least.

Comment: Sry, new to Stackoverflow...

A few questions I'd like to add:
Since the user has a password, I have to initiate the UserModule constructor with this password and store it in a field, then refer to it in the configure method. like:

`final String username;
final char[] password;

public UserModule(String username, char[] password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

@Override public void configure() {
    bind( User.class ).toInstance( new User( username, password) );
}`

Another question: Why can't I bind List to LinkedList or sth? In general classes from Java :[

Comment: Regarding "new to SO": No problem, be welcome. But you must understand that SO is not a chat site. This means, that other users want to find relevant questions to _their_ problems too. This is only possible when different problems are splitted into different questions. And especially the "List" question has been asked several time here. Regarding the first item: The important thing is the `bind(User.class).toInstance(...)` thing which you got right. How the username and password get into that place is not important. But it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will split my questions but I have another question concerning this:
So as you suggested I passed those arguments in the constructor of my UserModule but there is one simple problem. I want not exclude that the host and the port might vary so I have binded the constants HOST and PORT to @Named("Host"). So my User looks like this:  `User(@Named("Host") String host, @Named("Port") int port, String username, String password)`
How can I bind `User.class` to this instance without specifying host and port? I could pass both parameters but that would be redundant... Regards!

Comment: Now that I read my post again I think might have been a bit confusing...
The thing is, I need to create an instance of the User right away to ensure it exists in the database, so binding the constants Username and Password isn't an option. Moreover, having the password sitting as a constant through the application is not something I want. At this moment I solved it like ´final String host = "127.0.0.1"; int port = 1521; /* bind constants */ bind(User.class).toInstance(new User(host, port, name, pw);´

You know what I mean?

Best regards. :)

Answer (score 0):

The output of assisted injection is not injection - it's auto-wired factories (the facility is horribly named, sadly).

What gets produced by AssistedInject is a Factory - that Factory can be singleton.  But it's a factory, so it's job is to create objects, like the User object.  The internals of the Factory aren't set up to let it create Singleton value objects.  Value objects are, generally speaking, not singleton objects - you're using one here as "Context" rather than as data, and so you have a special case.

Also, your case is even more special because you want to pre-validate the data in the database before guice is even running.  This user is entirely context, not data, so don't use a factory to create it.  Create it manually, and if you need to use it elsewhere in guice-bound systems, then create it outside Guice, and pass it into a module as a DatabaseCredentials object or some such.

To properly help you we'd need to see a larger design concept, but my sense is, you're not thinking clearly about the difference between collaborators/services, value-types, context/configuration, etc. and that the confusion is largely coming because the word "User" is overloaded here.  Yes, it's a "user" but the database user isn't the same kind of user as other Users in the system - even if it is structurally identical, it means something different, has a different lifecycle, etc.